# How do I display all tables in a database as HTML tables?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have selected values from a single MySQL table and displayed them in a HTML table many times before using PHP, like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM main";

$result = $connection->query($query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['row1'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['row2'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['row3'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['row4'] . "</td>";
}
```

How can I display all of the tables in a certain database in the same way? I need it to be dynamic, so that if new tables are added to that database, they will show up on the webpage as well.

This is something I have tried, that doesn't seem to work. Perhaps I can get some feedback?

```
$query1 = "SHOW TABLES FROM db_name";

// This is equal to the number of tables in the database.
$query2 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM main";

$result1 = $connection->query($query1);

$result2 = $connection->query($query2);

$row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);

$count = $row2["COUNT(*)"];

$counter = 1;

while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
        ${getter.$counter++} = "SELECT * FROM " . $row[0];
    }

<table>
        <?php
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++) {
                ${request.$i} = $connection->query(${getter.$i});
                while ($row3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc(${request.$i})) {
                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['row1'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['row2'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['row3'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['row4'] . "</td>";
                }
        }
        ?>
</table>
```

Thanks.

Comment: so what you're really asking is how to ask mysql what tables exist in the database. after that, it's just a case of repeating your current process multiple times (loop through all the tables, for each one, query all the data for them, make a table, output it). Have you googled how to ask mysql what tables exist in a database? Once you know that, the solution is pretty trivial.

Comment: @ADyson I've just updated my original post with something I've tried that doesn't work, but I guess I am having trouble with the "loop through and output" part.

Comment: Thanks. What exactly isn't working? What output are you seeing? I'd expect you're having a problem with the field names, maybe? Since you don't know what the field names of each table will be, it would make more sense to fetch a non-associative array, and just loop through the fields until you reach the end of the row.

Comment: @ADyson Nothing is displayed on the page. In the error_log, it says "Use of undefined constant get" and "Use of undefined constant request".

Comment: It's because of this code `${request.$i}` (I mean for the second error, for example). ...it thinks `request` is some kind of constant variable. It's not very clear to me what you were trying to achieve with this code TBH, it seems to be rather over-complicating things.

Comment: to be clear, do you actually want to display all the data from each table, or just list the table names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to loop through all your tables and list the data from each one in a HTML table, including showing the column names, then this should work for you:

```
//get all the tables in the database
$sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM db_name";
$result = $connection->query($sql);

if ($result === false) die($conn->error);

//loop through the list of tables
while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
    echo "<h2>Table: ".$row[0]."</h2>";

    //now, for the current table, get all the data and loop through the rows
    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM ".$row[0];
    $result2 = $connection->query($sql2);

    if ($result2)
    {
        //get the column names
        $fields = $result2->fetch_fields();
        echo "<table><thead><tr>";

        //loop through the field names and output each one as a column heading
        foreach ($fields as $fld)
        {
          echo "<th>".$fld->name."</th>";
        }
        echo "</tr></thead><tbody>";

        //get the rows
        while ($row2 = $result2->fetch_row()) {
            echo "<tr>";

            //loop through each data value in the row and output into a HTML table cell
            foreach ($row2 as $cell) {
                echo "<td>".$cell."</td>";
            }
            echo "</tr>";
        }

        echo "</tbody></table><hr>";
    }
    else
    {
      echo "Problem retrieving data for ".$row[0].": ".$conn->error;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated Answer:

Try the following code

```php
<?php

require_once('includes/api/db-config.php');
$db = Database::getInstance();
$conn = $db->getConnection();
$dbname = 'databaseName';

$sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM {$dbname}";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

if (!$result) {
    echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn);
    exit;
}

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
    $tableSql = "SELECT * FROM {$row[0]}";
    $tableResult = mysqli_query($conn,$tableSql);
    $Response = "<tr>";
    while ($tableRow = mysqli_fetch_row($tableResult)) {
        $Response .= "<td>{$tableRow["id"]}</td>";
        $Response .= "<td>{$tableRow["title"]}</td>";
        $Response .= "<td>{$tableRow["description"]}</td>";
        $Response .= "<td>{$tableRow["action"]}</td>";
        $Response .= "<td>{$tableRow["mods"]}</td>";
        $Response .= "<td>{$tableRow["date"]}</td>";
    }
    $Response .= "</tr>";

}

?>
```

Now you have data from all the tables one by one now you can display the data in html table.

Comment: Kindly add your database structure

Comment: It's MySQL. For clarification, I need all of the rows of all of the tables in one database to be displayed in HTML.

Comment: No! Kindly share your table structure!

Comment: @UssaidIqbal It's not entirely clear, but I think the whole point is to be able to list all of the tables and data without knowing the structure in advance.

Comment: @UssaidIqbal All of the tables have the same exact structure. Here is a pic from phpmyadmin of one of them. https://imgur.com/a/259Tkr5

Comment: @user9740643 all your tables have the same structure??? In that case, why have you got separate tables? Everything could be placed in a single table. This smells like a de-normalised data model

Comment: Kindly check the updated answer just tested on one of my project and it worked fine!

Answer (score -1):

this works for me

```
require_once('db.php');

   $dbname = 'sport';

   $sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM $dbname"; $result =
   mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

   if (!$result) {
       echo "DB Error, could not list tables\n";
       echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn);
       exit; }

   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {   //print_r($row);
       echo "Table: {$row[0]}\n"; }
```

Comment: that solves the problem of listing the tables, but not the problem of outputting all the data from each table in turn into a HTML table. And also, code without any explanation is not actually very helpful to allow people to understand (rather than just blindly copy and paste)